# Text in safari canvas

Tags: html, text, canvas, safari

I have a problem with drawing text in safari canvas. It looks like on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heWRM.png). This canvas drawing on such way: first is drawing the stage block with gradient, than the talk block with gradient too and in talk block is drawing text, which in safari looks very agly.

**The code for drawing the text** :

```
function drawTimeInTalk(ctx, x, y, text) {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.font = "12px arial, sans-serif";
    ctx.textBaseline = 'alphabetic';
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}
```

**The code for drawing the stage gradient block:**

```
function fillGradRect(context, x, y, w, h, start_color, finish_color) {
    var grad = context.createLinearGradient(x, y, x, y + h);
    if (!start_color || !finish_color) {
        start_color = '#cbcbcb';
        finish_color = '#e5e5e5';
    }
    grad.addColorStop(0, start_color);
    grad.addColorStop(1, finish_color);
    context.fillStyle = grad;
    context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}
```

**The code for drawing the talk gradient block:**

```
function roundFillGradRect(context, x, y, w, h, radius, start_color, finish_color) {
    var grad = context.createLinearGradient(x, y, x, y + h);
    if (!start_color || !finish_color) {
        start_color = '#ffffff';
        finish_color = '#eeeeee';
    }
    grad.addColorStop(0, start_color);
    grad.addColorStop(1, finish_color);

    var r = x + w;
    var b = y + h;
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = grad;
    context.lineWidth = "1";
    context.moveTo(x + radius, y);
    context.lineTo(r - radius, y);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(r, y, r, y + radius);
    context.lineTo(r, y + h - radius);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(r, b, r - radius, b);
    context.lineTo(x + radius, b);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x, b, x, b - radius);
    context.lineTo(x, y + radius);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
    context.fill();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code or a live sample you can show us?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following javascript code `cn.style.webkitFontSmoothing="antialiased";` where cn is the canvas where the text is drawn. See also [Way around font transparency issues on canvas in Safari 5.1 on Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219338/way-around-font-transparency-issues-on-canvas-in-safari-5-1-on-lion)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same bug, but not always reproducible (sometimes the canvas is ok, sometimes not). The bug occurs when several complex and large canvas are drawn in the page. It seems that when the text is drawn, the background under it is not the right one. I also found that if i draw the text using a setTimeout, the number of time the bug occurs decreased (unfortunately it doesn't disappear in any case).

Comment: Thanks. But for me is strange that such behavior is only in safari on iMac and on all another devices in Safari canvas looks good. Why?